# Did the Senate buy the explanation of a mining disaster?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, death-star

In *Rogue One*, Director Krennic and Grand Moff Tarkin decided to test the capability of the Death Star by firing its superlaser at the Holy City on Jedha. In order to cover up what really happened, the event was labeled as a mining accident by other officials.

> **Darth Vader:** The Senate has been informed that Jedha was destroyed in
>   a mining disaster.

Did the Imperial Senate really buy this explanation? Could such an accident really blow a city up to orbit? Or were Vader & Co. only demonstrating their scorn on the Senate with the statement?

Comment: Given that the Emperor dissolves the Senate a few days later (*A New Hope*), my guess is that either the Senate didn't buy it and it was dissolved to quell dissent, or Vader and company knew the dissolution was coming and just needed to buy enough time until then. No sources unfortunately. Perhaps the novelization has more clues?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The cover story was extremely flimsy but it didn't matter since there was no investigation and the Senate was dissolved within the week.

> *“There is no Death Star,” Vader pronounced. “We’re informing the
> Senate that Jedha was destroyed in a mining disaster.”*
>
> ***Krennic knew that claim wouldn’t hold up to a close inspection, but
> the Empire could probably ensure no one ever managed such an
> investigation.** What choice did he have but to agree?*
>
> <sub><sup>[Rogue One: Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Rogue_One:_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

Comment: "The Empire could probably ensure no one ever managed such an investigation". Dissolving the Senate a few days later (*A New Hope*) and leaving only the regional governors, who report to the Emperor, definitely would do the trick.

Comment: Given that a bunch of senators were members of the Rebellion, they would undoubtedly have communicated with other Senators. Pointless though.